# Swift - Struct or Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, struct

In general, when storing dictionary style structured data such as:

```
let menuItems = [
    [
        "title": "View Profile",
        "icon": "iconSideProfile"
    ],
    [
        "title": "Invite Friends",
        "icon": "iconSideHeart"
    ],
    [
        "title": "Settings",
        "icon": "iconSideSettings"
    ],
    [
        "title": "Help",
        "icon": "iconSideHelp"
    ],
    [
        "title": "Logout",
        "icon": "iconSideLogout"
    ]
]
```

where we have an array of dictionaries that contain a title and an icon, is it better practice to store the dictionaries as dictionaries or structs?

```
struct MenuItem {
    let title: String
    let icon: String
}

let menuItems = [
    MenuItem(title: "View Profile", icon: "iconSideProfile"),
    ...
]
```

The advantages of storing in a struct being that the data is better defined, meaning you don't have to explicitly say that the dictionary will contain this key in some cases etc.

Or is this too wasteful of resources?

Comment: Why would you think using a struct is more wasteful than using a dictionary?  More wasteful of *what* resources?

Comment: I would guess there's more overhead in the use of structs compared to dictionaries so wasteful of memory resources. Or are they similar?

Comment: In the dictionary, you're storing 4 strings for each menu item. With the struct it's 2 strings for each menu item. You should definitely use a `struct` here; and not even for the more efficient use of memory, you should use it because it's the stronger type.

Comment: Not so much in this example (where @Hamish has the right answer), but in other situations where you find yourself with key-value data, also consider using a custom `enum` as your key instead of a `String`. Strongly typed instead of stringly typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify one point when you are worried about memory resources by using `struct`. A structure is value copied passed type. **It's not stored in the memory heap unlike classes (Reference types).**

So go and use `struct`, it's recommended by Apple itself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is always better to use data structures (struct or class). Using a dictionary is error prone, uses more memory, uses more CPU time, and costs you tons of man-hours when you have to find and fix bugs that don't show up until the software is running and crashing. Typos in the names of variables get caught by the compiler but typos in strings used as keys to a dictionary just cause weird errors while the software is running and sometimes those show up long after you moved on and some poor soul is stuck maintaining this code.

A dictionary is for when you have a lot of different and usually unpredictable strings for the keys. You have the same two strings over and over and they will never change. There is no reason not to use a struct or a class and every reason to avoid using the dictionary like you show in your question. To be blunt, that dictionary is plain bad code and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: That's not entirely true, use a struct will use more memory and CPU as copying between stack methods. But dictionary is slower to read as accessing from the heap. That's the tradeoff.

Comment: @Alex Bin Zhao, suing a dictionary is a bad technique and leads to errors. I experienced this fiurst hand where a lazy programmer before me used a dictionary for just ab out everything and there was data in that dictionary that was "defined" at the point of being added to the dictionary. Had they used a constant, at least they could have avoided the spelling error that caused the bug.

Comment: Since a dictionary has no definition and items can be added in multiple places, the only way to debug any of that code is to do a search of every dictionary "add" call and see if it's to that dictionary and uses a key that is correct and spelled correctly. I stand by saying that it is terrible programming technique to use a dictionary for predetermined data where a struct or class would work just as well. If performance is an issue, don't pass a struct by vallue, pass a reference!