# Determing dictionary with nested dictionaries type in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a dictionary of the following structuring, and I need to declare its type to avoid errors such as "Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'String'" when indexing its nested dictionaries.

```
@State var data = [
    "base" : "baseLanguage",
    "target" : "targetLanguage",
    "languages" : [
        "language" : [
            "target" : true,
            "strings" : [
                "..." : [
                    "translation" : "...",
                    "pinned" : false,
                    "order" : 0
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Xcode identifies the type as "[String : Any]" but I want it to be of the following type. I'm not sure what the correct syntax is for this type when declaring @State var data: type.

```
[
    String : String,
    String : String,
    String : [
        String : [
            String : Bool,
            String : [
                String : [
                    String : String,
                    String : Bool,
                    String : Int
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Don't use a dictionary for this. Create your own structs.

Comment: I looked into creating a Struct but I didn't see the point in using one over a dictionary

Comment: Well now you see the point. If you used a struct you wouldn't be stuck on finding the type for the dictionary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873542/swift-struct-or-dictionary#:~:text=The%20advantages%20of%20storing%20in,key%20in%20some%20cases%20etc.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: And the type you want is [String : Any]. Because there is a string and an array as value against a key which is String. So there is no other way to describe a type that can have array or string other than any. You can just use struct.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to convert the nested language dictionary to a struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much much better. Never go back ;) Note that:

- First letter of structs should be capitalised. ( Linter will shoot if you don't. )
- You can sometimes embed structs, to enforce scoping. It's up to you and depends of the situation.
- You don't have to use Array<> and Dictionary<> notations. Prefer brackets.
- Define a 'string' datatype is not really advised, since it already defines a primitive type. Note that you can use `String` between quotes to redefine primitive types in your scope, but it is a bad practice.

```swift
struct Data: Hashable {
    struct Text: Hashable {
        let translation: String
        let pinned: Bool
        let order: Int
    }

    struct Language: Hashable {
        let language: String
        let target: Bool
        let texts: [String: Text]
    }
    
    let base: String
    let target: String
    let languages: [Language]
}
```

If you need to use `Text` type outside:

```
var text: Data.Text
```

And finally, It's a bit curious to define an array of translations in a `Language` type. Maybe you should name it `Translations` and structure a bit differently. for example have a `Text` struct that contains a `Translations` dict, with language code as the key. Just a suggestion.. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll mark this as the answer. I did however want to note that since these values are meant to be changed by the application and/or used as binding states (i.e. target: Bool), Xcode suggests they should be var rather than let.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting this as an answer to my own question, based on comments encouraging the use of Structs. The contents of this data variable is identical to the original post, but reformatted to use Structs.

```
struct data: Hashable {
    let base: String
    let target: String
    let languages: Array<language>
}

struct language: Hashable {
    let language: String
    let target: Bool
    let strings: Dictionary<String, string>
}

struct string: Hashable {
    let translation: String
    let pinned: Bool
    let order: Int
}

@State var database = data(
    base: "baseLanguage",
    target: "targetLanguage",
    languages: [
        language(
            language: "language",
            target: true,
            strings: [
                "..." : string(translation: "...", pinned: false, order: 0)
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: Much much better :) I give you few tips in another answer below. Maybe you might use it.